# File not saved using FileOutputStream and InputStream

Tags: android

I'm getting data from an api and I want to write/save some file with that data. This is my code

```
try
        {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();

            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

             File myDir = new File(root + "/incubate_files");
             if (!myDir.exists()) myDir.mkdirs();

             File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+File.separator+"/incubate_files/", "messageId_"+messageId+"."+ext);
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0;

            while((bufferLength = content.read(buffer)) != -1)
                output.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);

            output.close();
            output.flush();

            content.close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

There is no exception, only a empty file

Thanks!

UPDATE

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
                    builder.append(line);
}

Log.d(app.TAG,"Cadena: "+builder.toString());

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(builder.toString().getBytes());
```

I change my InputStream white the content of the api. The api returns a lot of characters. The image actually exists in the server and I can see it.

Now the file is with some bytes but I cant see in my phone

The api reponse is in binary

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of `getInputStream` method from connection object and save the data into a `File`. For example:

```
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();    
File file = new File("download_directory_path", "file_name");
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bufferLength = 0;

while((bufferLength = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
    output.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
```

and then finally `close()` your `output` and `input` streams.

Once, writing is complete, the `file` points to the downloaded file.

Comment: I did that, the file is created but without content. :(. The APIS return a content

Comment: perhaps you should edit your question with the implemented code or ask a new question regarding the new problem

Comment: did you call `output.flush();` right before calling `ouput.close();`?

Comment: You need to flush first and then call close on output.